# In what way does this HEVC video not comply to Apples's requirements document?

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, quicktime, hevc

My goal is to work out why a given video file does not play on Macos/Safari/Quicktime.

The background to this question is that it is possible to play HEVC videos with a transparent background/alpha channel on Safari/MacOS.  To be playable, a video must meet the specific requirements set out by Apple in this document:

https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/HEVC-Video-with-Alpha-Interoperability-Profile.pdf

The video that does not play on Apple/Safari/Quicktime is an HEVC video with an alpha transparency channel.  Note that VLC for MacOS DOES play this file. Here it is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZnXjcDbk-_YxTgRuH_D7RSR9SXdY_XTv/view?usp=share_link

I have two example HEVC video files with a transparent background/alpha channel, and they both play fine using either Quicktime player or Safari:

Working video #1:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PJAyg_sVKVvb-Py8PAu42c1qm8l2qCbh/view?usp=share_link

Working video #2:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kk8ssUyT7qAaK15afp8VPR6mIWPFX8vQ/view?usp=sharing

The first step is to work out in what way my non-working video ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZnXjcDbk-_YxTgRuH_D7RSR9SXdY_XTv/view?usp=share_link ) does not comply with the specification.

Once it is clear which requirements are not met by the non-working video then I can move onto the next phase, which is to try to formulate an ffmpeg command that will output a video meeting the requirements.

I have read Apples requirements document and I am out of my depth in trying to analyse the non working video against the requirements - I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone suggest a way to identify what is wrong with the video?

Additional context is that I am trying to find a way to create Apple/MacOS compatible alpha channel / transparent videos using ffmpeg with hevc_nvenc running on an Intel machine.  I am aware that Apple hardware can create such videos, but for a wide variety of reasons it is not practical for me to use Apple hardware to do the job.  I have spent many hours trying all sorts of ffmpeg and ffprobe commands to try to work out what is wrong and modify the video to fix it, but to be honest most of my attempts are guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple specification for an alpha layer in HEVC requires that the encoder process and store the alpha in a certain manner. It also requires that the stream configuration syntax be formed in a specific manner. At time of writing, I'm aware of only the videotoolbox HEVC encoder being capable of emitting such a stream.